# How to reset a Hogan.js template used in typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, hogan.js

Im new to both Hogan.js and typeahead.js so this question is probably silly.

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({                              
      name: 'twitter-oss',                                                        
      prefetch: 'repos.json',                                             
      template: [                                                                 
        '<p class="type">{{language}}</p>',                              
        '<p class="name">{{name}}</p>',                                      
        '<p class="description">{{description}}</p>'
      ].join(''),
      engine: Hogan
});
```

This is how I created my instance of typeahead.js with Hogan.js as template. 
Now that I want to change my test-data: 'repos.json', the template is still the same. I guess its cached somehow. How can I reset my template to contain new data?

I see hogan have a compile(); and render() method, but I dont understand how to use it.

I use the newest version of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of typeahead.js (0.9.3), datasets are cached by their name property and there's no way to [bust the cache](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/221). So if you have:

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'twitter-oss',                                                        
  prefetch: 'repos.json',                                             
  template: [                                                                 
    '<p class="type">{{language}}</p>',                              
    '<p class="name">{{name}}</p>',                                      
    '<p class="description">{{description}}</p>'
  engine: Hogan
});

$('.example-something-different .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  prefetch: 'something_different.json'
});
```

`.example-something-different .typeahead` wouldn't use the configuration specified, it'd use the configuration specified by `.example-twitter-oss .typeahead` because they use the same `name`. This isn't intuitive and it's something that will be changing in the next release, v0.10. For now though, you can circumvent this problem by using different `name`s:

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  prefetch: 'repos.json',
  template: [
    '<p class="type">{{language}}</p>',
    '<p class="name">{{name}}</p>', 
    '<p class="description">{{description}}</p>'
  ].join(''),
  engine: Hogan
});

$('.example-something-different .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'something different',
  prefetch: 'something_different.json'
});
```